# Ruby Namespace conflict with module class instance variable defined in a method and using attr:

Tags: ruby, module

I am trying to familiarize myself with modules and this code shows a name clash in main that I can not find any information on how to resolve using a namepace (only) with a module class instance variable.  Perhaps not possible?

**Modified code slightly so  "c = "MAIN"" is before "include" so no doubt that two c variables exist.  Added class so I can specify 'cv::a' which I believe is an example of an explicit receiver as you mentioned. I deliberately created the name collision just to see if I could resolve it (main::c was defined before include in my original code from which this was snipped)

I guess my theoretical question becomes can I in some manner specify an explicit receiver (like M2.C) for the instance variable 'c' defined in a method, the similar to that of 'a' (cv::a) defined in a class.

I had decided probably not possible as I was unable to code a namespace to prefix 'c' but thought to ask thinking I had missed something.
If this is possible using my code, could you show me how to do so.*

```
module M2
def method_vars() @c = "@C"; @d = "@D";  end  
attr :c; attr :d

class Class_var
  def   init()  @a = "A"; @b = "B"; end
  attr :a; attr :b
end
end
c = "MAIN" 
include M2  
method_vars()
puts ">#{c}<--->#{d}<"  # >MAIN<--->@D<
cv = Class_var.new
cv.init()
puts ">#{cv::a}<--->#{cv::b}<" # >A<--->B<  
exit
```

Comment: Local variables are always selected over methods - this is *only an "issue" at the scope of usage*, as `@c` has not been altered. Choose better names and/or leave the module in a tidy scope, eg. `M2.c` (with an explicit receiver the local variable will never be selected).

Answer (score 0):

The only purpose of the question was to determine if I could isolate the two variables 'c' using the module's namespace.

Perhaps I did not ask the question properly.   What I previously had tried led me to believe this was not possible (except for class variables).

I am going to assume that the answer is that it can not be done.